# Performance testing with Locust with mocking 3rd party API

Tags: python, testing, performance-testing, load-testing, locust

I came across an issue with performance testing of payments-related endpoints.
Basically I want to test some endpoints that make request themselves to a 3rd-party providers' API.
Is it possible from Locust's tests level to mock those 3rd-party API for the endpoints I intend to actually test (so without interference with the tested endpoints)?

Comment: what have you tried so far please ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a service you'd like to load/performance test but that service calls out to a third-party. But when you do your testing, you don't want to actually make any calls to the third-party service?

Locust is used for simulating client behavior. You can define that client behavior to be whatever you want; typically it's primary use case is for making http calls but almost any task can be done.

If it's your client that makes a request to your service and then makes a separate request to the other third-party service for payment processing, yes, you could define some sort of mocking behavior in Locust to make a real call to your service and then mock out a payment call. But if it's your service that takes a client call and then makes its own call to the third-party payment service, no, Locust can't do anything about that.

For that scenario, you'd be best off making your own simple mock/proxy service of the third-party service. It would take a request from your service, do basic validation to ensure things are coming in as expected, and then just return some canned response that looks like what your service would expect from the third-party. But this would be something you'd have to host yourself and have a method of telling your service to point to this mock service instead (DNS setting, environment variable, etc.). Then you could use Locust to simulate your client behavior as normal and you can test your service in an isolated manner without making any actual calls to the third-party service.

Answer (score 0):

I actually skipped the most important part of the issue, namely I am testing the endpoints from outside of the repo containing them (basically my load test repo calls my app repo). I ended up mocking the provider inside of the app repo, which I initially intended to avoid but turned out to be only reasonable solution at the moment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).